# How should I package my Language Server with my client?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a language server for VSCode. It's made up of a client and a server, communicating over RPC.

The official docs have a [working example](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-language-server), with the language-server split into in two directories, the `client` and the `server`.

What I want to do is to package both into a VSIX file, so I can install them together.

In their example, they say `cd` to the `client` directory and run `vsce package`. However, If I do that and install the resultant package, VSCode says

> "Error: Cannot find module '/home/blah/vscode.language-client-example-0.0.1/server/server.js"

I can't run `vsce package` in the `server` directory, as it complains

> "Error: Missing publisher name"

How do I package it?

Comment: "I'm trying to create a language server for VSCode." -> if you're doing a Language Server, it should be for more than VSCode ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can publish extension and try. [Official doc for publishing extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/publish-extension)

In short for publishing, follow below steps

1. `npm install -g vsce`
2. `vsce publish`

Comment: Your question says you used `vsce package` not the `vsce publish` command.

Comment: Yes, because I don't want to publish it publicly

Answer (score 0):

Both for packaging as well as publishing you need to register a publisher.

In the docs they explain how to create a publisher for yourself:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#create-a-publisher

Then in your (root) `package.json` add your publisher id: `"publisher": "my-publisher"`

After that both `package` and `publish` should work with `vsce`.